# What's the problem with fsck.ext3?

Tags: filesystems, utilities, fsck

It seems there is some problem with my HDD in my satellite box. The box records to and plays video from the HDD, but occasionally it hangs (it was stable before). It's Linux version 2.6.32.28_stm24_0207, ext3 filesystem.

I wanted to check the filesystem using `fsc.ext3` to be sure it's ok. But this problem occurs:

```
# fsck.ext3 /dev/sda1
fsck.ext3: symbol lookup error: fsck.ext3: undefined symbol: test_io_backing_manager
```

The tool reports this error even when stated without any parameters. The partition can be mounted or not, always the same problem.

Does this mean there is a problem with `fsck` itself? How do I repair it?
Is there any diagnostic to find more info?

**Update:**
`uname -a` gives this output:

```
Linux ipbox99 2.6.32.28_stm24_0207 #45 PREEMPT Thu Jun 6 13:57:56 CEST 2013 sh4 GNU/Linux
```

It's [ABIPBox 99 HD](http://www.abcomeu.com/99hd) with firmware update [20130610](http://download.abcom.sk/abcomeu.php?direction=0&order=nom&directory=AB%20IPBox%2099xxHD/99HD%20images&).

Comment: The `fsck` binary is incompatible with one of the libraries. Do you know what Linux distribution this is (the kernel version isn't very useful, except that `stm24` may be a hint)? If not, what is the exact model of satellite box, and what version/upgrade level? What does `lsb_release -a` say? What about `ldd /sbin/fsck.ext3`?

Comment: @Gilles you [can't be sure](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) whether it's in `/sbin` or `/usr/bin`, better do `ldd $(which fsck.ext3)` instead

Comment: @strugee I hesitated but wanted to keep things simple. If `/sbin` is a symlink to `/usr/sbin` or vice versa, it doesn't matter. If `/usr` may be separated then `fsck` has to be in `/`. I don't know any distribution that puts `fsck` in `/usr/sbin` where `/sbin` isn't a symlink to `/usr/sbin`, is there one?

Comment: @Gilles not that I know of either. the linked Freedesktop page says that `/usr/sbin` should be a symlink to `/usr/bin`

Comment: @Gilles: None of `lsb_release` and `ldd` are not installed. I added more information into my question.